# luatexja-fontspec biblatex error

Tags: biblatex, japanese

I have gotten a errors from using luatexja-fontspec with the biblatex style trad-alpha. I am wanting to use this biblatex style with a bibliography entry which includes Japanese. A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}

\usepackage[style=trad-alpha,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mwe.bib}

\begin{document}
    
textttttttt \cite{Sato--1981} \cite{Sato-Sato--1983}
    
\printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

And the mwe.bib file:

```
@InProceedings{Sato-Sato--1983,
    author       = {Sato, Mikio and Sato, Yasuko},
    booktitle    = {Nonlinear partial differential equations in applied science},
    title        = {Soliton equations as dynamical systems on infinite-dimensional {G}rassmann manifold},
    year         = {1983},
    pages        = {259--271},
    publisher    = {North-Holland},
    series       = {North-Holland Math. Stud.},
    volume       = {81},
}

@Article{Sato--1981,
    author   = {Sato, Mikio},
    journal  = {数理解析研究所講究録},
    title    = {{Soliton equations as dynamical systems on an infinite dimensional Grassmann manifolds}},
    year     = {1981},
    pages    = {30--46},
    volume   = {439},
}
```

Running LuaLaTeX after cleaning auxiliary files, the process gets caught in recompiling the bibliography and never finishes. If I omit the luatexja-fontspec package, then there are no errors, but then the Japanese characters do not print. Compiling this a second time with luetexja-fontspec added back in, then gives the correct pdf, but with errors.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The example works for me on a current MikTeX installation. Can you please share the `.log` file of the failing LuaLaTeX run? Have you tried to typeset Japanese characters directly in your document without going through the bibliography and via `biblatex`? Does that work?

Comment: @moewe The log file can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/132c61oegQS7ZwE9TFmptprN36JhAslsJ/view?usp=sharing The compilation was manually stopped after it stalled. The pdf output was one line: textttttttt [Sato–1981] [Sato-Sato–1983]

Comment: @moewe I don't know if I understand you suggestion on typesetting directly the characters. I opted to not use the CJK package thinking lualatex would be easier.

Comment: you shouldn't use bibtex with japanese. Use biber. Beside this: I can reproduce your error in texlive 2019, but it compiles fine in texlive 2021.

Comment: It also compiles in texlive 2019 if I use biber.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for figuring that out. I am running texlive 2019. I will see if iI can get it to work for me.